# Why do I get this error: 'import of module appears within namespace' on xcode with react-native?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, glog

I got this react-native project and I had to use `use_modular_headers!` on `Podfile`. I suppose I needed that because this `pod MercadoPagoSDK` is some sort of dynamic library (╯°□°）╯ which I don't really know what that means on iOS development world.

Now I'm getting this error during build on xcode!

`import of module 'glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google'`

I am not finding a solution to this `user_modular_headers!` thing. I already tried all ideas from here https://github.com/google/glog/issues/393 but I am afraid none of them worked.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to add the following code to your podfile, including the modular_headers part:

`pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false`

for more information check out the full thread here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26217